# How to get data-attr when click table row

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, custom-data-attribute

I have table and I want to get a data attribute of column "geometry" of the row which is clicked. So what I am doing is:

```
var row = jQuery(this).closest("tr");
```

Above code is to get that row which is clicked and the below code is to get data attribute from column geometry, my data attribute is `data-geomet`.

```
var text = row.find("geometry").data("geomet");
console.log(text);
```

I am getting text `undefined`. I get `text()` of class geometry but could not get data attribute.

Example HTML:

```
<td class="geometry" data-geomet="${obj["Details"]}"> details["geometry"]</td></tr>
```

**UPDATE**

```
    %for obj in tableData:
        var details=JSON.parse('${obj["Details"]}');
        var data = "<tr><td> <a href='#gMap' class='fence_data'>${obj['Geofence_Name']}</a></td>";
        data += "<td>${obj['Vehicle_Id']}</td>";
        if(details["type"]===undefined){
            data += '<td>NA</td>';  
        }
        else{
            data += '<td class="type"> '+details["type"]+'</td>';
        }
        if(details["radius"]===undefined){
            data += '<td>NA</td>';  
        }
        else{
            data+='<td class="radius"> '+details["radius"]+'</td>';
        }
        if(details["geometry"]===undefined){
            data += '<td>NA</td></tr>'; 
        }
        else{
            data += '<td class="geometry" data-geomet="${obj["Details"]}"> '+details["geometry"]+'</td></tr>';
        }
       table.append(data)

    %endfor
```

Here is an example  jsfiddle.net/3vmL5277/2 where I am getting undefined.

Comment: Please post your HTML. I would imagine the selector in `find()` is wrong though. You probably need something like: `var text = row.find(".geometry").data("geomet");`

Comment: @Rory <td class="geometry" data-geomet="${obj["Details"]}"> details["geometry"]</td></tr>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your HTML in this format:

```
<td class="geometry" data-geomet="${obj["Details"]}"> details["geometry"]</td></tr>
```

This code should work for you:

```
// assuming this code is in an event handler
// and 'this' refers to an element within a 'tr' element
var $row = jQuery(this).closest("tr");
var text = $row.find(".geometry").data("geomet");
console.log(text);
```

Comment: I have tryed this before and now still getting undefiend

Comment: Can you post a complete example of your HTML and JS. I feel like I'm only seeing half of the issue.

Comment: @CY5 Missing `.` at `$row.find("geometry").data("geomet");` , try adjust to `$row.find(".geometry").data("geomet");`

Comment: inside ${obj["Details"]} i string like this "{type:"Circle"}" so iam getting "{" in data-geomet why so?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what your HTML markup looks like, here's something assuming that your accurate tds are attached to a class called 'geometry':

```
$('.geometry').on('click',function(){
   var myDataAttr = $(this).data('geomet');
   console.log(myDataAttr);
   });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3vmL5277/

EDIT:
**Here's a new example according to your comment:**

```
$('tr').on('click',function(){
   var myDataAttr = $(this).find('td.geometry').data('geomet');
   console.log(myDataAttr);
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3vmL5277/3/

Comment: your example was good, but i wanted if i click on cell1 then i should get cell2 data-attr from your example can you tell me please how to do it?

Comment: I have used your example and modified it to show my problem ok here jsfiddle.net/3vmL5277/2 i am getting undefined

Comment: I updated my example according to your comment. Have a look in the second fiddle:)